# How to "view" next line of string in a text file without switching lines?

Tags: matlab, file

I am trying to read in information line by line from a text file. I already have it such that it reads a line, stores it in variables, then goes to next line, stores in variables, etc (so line 1 --> line 2 --> line 3 etc.).

Code:

```
'some while loop here'

str=textscan(read_in, '%s', 1, 'delimiter', '\n');
str=str{:}{:};
[str1]=textscan(str, '%d %s %d %f %f %f %f %s %d %f');

'end loop'
```

I would like to keep this working, however I'd like the ability to get the information from the next line as well (ie. if I'm on line 3, I'd like to get info from line 4 without actually "moving" to line 4 of the text file).

Ex: I would read in '1 a b c' into one variable (call it *currLine*), '2 d e f' into another variable (*nextLine*). So after one line, I have info from line 1 and 2. I would then like *currLine* to read '2 d e f' and *nextLine* to read ' 3 g h i'.

```
1 a b c
2 d e f
3 g h i
.......
```

My current issue is that whenever I try to use 'nextLine', it advances the "pointer" of the text file (for lack of better word) to line 3. So after 1 iteration I would have

```
currLine = '1 a b c'
nextLine = '2 d e f'
```

2nd iteration:

```
currLine = '3 g h i'
nextLine = '......'
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ftell`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ftell.html) and [`fseek`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fseek.html) to adjust your position within the file. `ftell` will tell you the current position in the file and `fseek` allows you to move to any arbitrary position within the file. You could store the current position after reading the current line and then  `fseek` back to this position after reading the next line.

```
% Read current line
textscan(fid, '%s', 1);

% Remember where we are in the file
pos = ftell(fid);

% Read the next line
textscan(fid, '%s', 1)

% Now go back to where we were
fseek(fid, pos)
```

This can get pretty inefficient though. A better approach may be to have a variable which holds the next line and at the beginning of your loop, assign the current value to that variable.

```
this_line = '';

while true
    % Read next line
    next_line = textscan(fid, '%s', 1);

    % Do stuff with the two

    % Move onto the next line
    this_line = next_line;
end
```

Comment: Cheers! Kind of already had that except the 'this_line = new_line;' part! Should have definitely realized I could just hold it in the 'next_line' variable and then afterwards assign to 'this_line'!